# Rotate with joystick while maintaining the angle of rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, rotation, quaternions

I'm using a free FPS asset for Unity that adds controls for smartphones. In the CameraRotation method, I'm trying to set up a camera. In normal behavior, when turning the joystick, the camera continues to move until the user releases the joystick. I need to make it look like a touchpad or mouse control when the user moves the joystick and the camera rotates once without continuing to move.

The original code is this:

```
_rotationVelocity = _input.look.x * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

// rotate the player left and right
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * _rotationVelocity);
```

I create a rotation like this:

```
// Calculate the rotation based on the input
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-_input.look.y * RotationSpeed,
    _input.look.x * RotationSpeed, 0f);

// Rotate the transform immediately
transform.rotation = targetRotation;
```

In the first case, the camera constantly rotates while holding the joystick, and in the second, it rotates as I need (the user moves the joystick, the camera rotates and stops rotating), but when I try to move the joystick again, it returns to the previous position (due to the value of _input.look).
I don’t understand how to rotate the camera in the second way, while maintaining the rotation for the next movement of the joystick.